# JavaScript: Trim .toPrecision() trailing zeros

Tags: javascript, math, precision

I am creating an online calculator using JavaScript.

I have this to work out a calculation:

```
eval(expression).toPrecision(10);
```

This produces the right output in almost all cases. E.g.

```
eval('456456+45646486*45646884').toPrecision(10)
// Output: "2.083619852e+15"

eval('1/0').toPrecision(10)
// Output: "Infinity"
```

However

```
eval('4*1').toPrecision(10)
// Output: "4.000000000"
```

How do I trim the trailing zeros **but** also keep nice outputs above?

Comment: `numb = (Math.round(numb * 100000000)) / 100000000);`

Comment: Thanks guys but both these suggestions only cover the 2nd and 3rd examples but now the first example produces "2083619852000000" rather than "2.083619852e+15"

Comment: Be sure `expression` is generated by *you* and not by a third party. That is, read the input and generate `expression` based on that, since [`eval()` on unsafe code is unsafe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

only all-zero decimals

```
  eval('4*1').toPrecision(10).replace(/\.0+$/,"")
```

zero ending decimals:

```
  eval('4.5*1').toPrecision(10).replace(/\.([^0]+)0+$/,".$1")
```

edit: handle both all zero and ending zero cases

EDIT: if you will ALWAYS use .toPrecision() first, and thus always have a ".", you can trim off any trailing zeros:

```
  eval('4.5*1').toPrecision(10).replace(/0+$/,"")
```

EDIT: handling trailing decimals:

```
eval('4.5*0').toPrecision(10).replace(/\.?0+$/,"")
```

Comment: Almost, but `eval('4+0.0001').toPrecision(10).replace(/\.0+$/,"")` gives "4.000100000" rather than "4.0001"

Comment: gotcha, added two other options for that. let me know if something more complex is required.

Comment: Regex to the rescue? That last edit I think nailed it! I'll give it a more thorough test and accept if its good to go! Many thanks.

Comment: Is there anyway of improving it slightly for whole numbers? i.e. "2" instead of "2."?

Comment: @greg: added to answer. i think that last one is THE one, have a good feeling about it...

Comment: So long as I don't use numbers beginning with 0's like `04.5+10` I think this should be alright...

Comment: All of these result in trailing `0`s for certain input. Precision of 2 for `/\.0+$/,""` will return `0.040` for `.04*1`. Precision of 2 for `/\.([^0]+)0+$/,".$1"` will return `0.040` for `.04*1`. Precision of 2 for `/0+$/,""` will return `4.` for `4*1`. Precision of 2 for `/\.?0+$/,""` will return `4` for `40*1`.

Comment: (I specified that those examples messed up when the precision was 2. The input can be altered to result in the same issue with a precision of 10.) [`eval('4000000000*1').toPrecision(10).replace(/\.?0+$/,"")` becomes `4` instead of `4000000000`.](http://jsfiddle.net/bfrohs/06uw0fo4/) And I never said `/\.?0+$/,""` would mess up `0.04*1`. I said `/\.0+$/,""` and `/\.([^0]+)0+$/,".$1"` would. Look at the Stack Snippet in my answer to see the numbers your answer's methods mess up on.

Comment: we were only interested in toPrecision(10), it's not a universal solution, which would be a lot more complex...

Answer (score 21):

Divide by 1 after using toPrecision.
Javascript will trail the zeros, and there's no regexes needed.

Comment: i used this solution like this: `val.toFixed(2) / 1`

Comment: This works because in javascript division between string and number returns a number type and same applies if you do multiplication by 1

Comment: I think this is the answer most people (not OP) are probably after. ex: `eval('456456+45646486*45646884').toPrecision(10) ` == `2.083619852e+15` like op wants, but casting it to a number (`/1`) yields the _subjectively_ uglier `2083619852000000`

Comment: That's actually pretty efficient.

Comment: Weird solution but it works

Answer (score 4):

The following `replace()` call will replace all trailing `0`s and a trailing `.`, if present:

```
eval(expression).toPrecision(10).replace(/(?:\.0+|(\.\d+?)0+)$/, "$1")
```

## How does it work?

`/(?:\.0+|(\.\d+?)0+)$/` looks for `\.0+` or `(\.\d+?)0+` at the end of the string ([`$`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6298566/526741)). The `?:` prevents `\.0+|(\.\d+?)0+` from being ["captured"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/526741).

`\.0+` will match `.` followed by any number of `0`s.

`(\.\d+?)0+` will match `.` followed by at least one digit followed by at least one `0`. The [`?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9623879/526741) makes sure the `0+` matches as many `0`s as possible. The parentheses "capture" the non-`0`s.

The second parameter on `replace()` is the new string to replace what was matched. The `$1` is a variable of sorts and tells `replace()` to replace the matched value with the first captured value (because `1` was after the `$`). In this case, the first captured value was whatever `\.\d+?` matched.

So, in the end:

1. `.` followed by any number of `0`s will be discarded
2. `.` followed by non-`0`s followed by `0`s will have the `0`s discarded

## Examples

For comparison of methods for precisions of `1`, `2`, and `3` for `.40*1`, `4*1`, and `40*1`, see below. First (bold) item in each group is this method. Red items are those that don't match expectations.

```js
var tests = [
  '.04*1',
  '.40*1',
  '4*1',
  '40*1'
];
var results = {};
for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i += 1) {
  results[i] = {};
  for (var p = 1; p < 3; p += 1) {
    results[i][p] = {};
    results[i][p][0] = {
      'output': eval(tests[i]).toPrecision(p).replace(/(?:\.0+|(\.\d+?)0+)$/, "$1"),
      'regex': '/(?:\.0+|(\.\d+?)0+)$/, "$1"'
    };
    results[i][p][1] = {
      'output': eval(tests[i]).toPrecision(p).replace(/\.0+$/, ""),
      'regex': '/\.0+$/, ""'
    };
    results[i][p][2] = {
      'output': eval(tests[i]).toPrecision(p).replace(/\.([^0]+)0+$/, ".$1"),
      'regex': '/\.([^0]+)0+$/, ".$1"'
    };
    results[i][p][3] = {
      'output': eval(tests[i]).toPrecision(p).replace(/0+$/, ""),
      'regex': '/0+$/, ""'
    };
    results[i][p][4] = {
      'output': eval(tests[i]).toPrecision(p).replace(/\.?0+$/, ""),
      'regex': '/\.?0+$/, ""'
    };
  }
}
for (var i in results) {
  $("#result").append("<h1>" + tests[i] + "</h1>");
  for (var p in results[i]) {
    var expected = null;
    for (var t in results[i][p]) {
      var div = $("<div></div>");
      if (t == 0) {
        expected = results[i][p][t].output;
        div.addClass("expected");
      } else if (results[i][p][t].output !== expected) {
        div.addClass("invalid");
      }
      div.append("P" + p + ": " + results[i][p][t].output);
      div.append(" <small>" + results[i][p][t].regex + "</small>");
      $("#result").append(div);
    }
    $("#result").append("<br>");
  }
}
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace; }
.expected { font-weight: bold; }
.invalid { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: simply using $2 instead of $1 would simplify and run faster than non-capturing groups.

Comment: @dandavis "Simplfy" is subjective. When dealing with complex regex, I find only capturing groups you're actually going to use greatly simplifies things in the long run. And that isn't what I've [found with some experimenting](http://jsperf.com/capturing-vs-non-capturing-math). Yes, with Chrome 37, it's faster to use capturing groups, but Firefox 33 seems to perform just as well regardless of the method used. And, a couple of times I ran the test, Firefox performed *better* with non-capturing groups.