# Return NonMatching Part of Regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm currenty trying to format some parts of a Brandname, but I'm stuck with getting the part that I need to format, example:

`BrandTest®`
`BrandBottle®`
`BrandJuice®`

I would like to have the parts between `Brand` and the `®`.

I currently tried something like: `/(?=(Brand))+(.*)+(®)/`

But I'm getting everything except the part in the middle.

Comment: You didn't well understand what is a lookahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your regex to use this:

```
Brand(.*?)®
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eA6xU3/1)**

Php code

```
$re = "/Brand(.*?)®/"; 
$str = "BrandTest® BrandBottle® BrandJuice®"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
<?php
$brands = 'BrandTest® BrandBottle® BrandJuice®';
$brands = explode('Brand', $brands);
//you will get each brand in an array as:
//"Test®", "Bottle®", "Juice®"
?>
```

If you don't want the `®` then this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/9826656/4977144

Answer (score 0):

Roll it up into a method and return your result:

```
function getQueryPiece($queryString) {
    preg_match('/\?\=Brand(.*)®/',$queryString,$matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

getQueryPiece("?=BrandBottle®"); // string(6) Bottle  
getQueryPiece("?=BrandTest®"); // string(4) Test  
getQueryPiece("?=BrandJuice®"); // string(5) Juice
```

This defines only 1 capturing group (the piece of the string between `?=Brand` and `®`).  If you need to capture the other parts as well, just wrap each part in parens: `'/(\?\=Brand)(.*)(®)/'` However this will alter the position of that piece in the `$matches` array.  It would be position 2.

I believe the initial problem in your pattern is the result of using '?' unescaped. Question marks have special meanings in regular expressions.  Here's a good write up regarding that: [Regex question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623879/regex-question-mark)